# フレンドクラスを使うときの名前空間について

Tags: c++

お世話になります。

テストの際にどうしてもprivateメンバを触りたい場面があり、
フレンドクラスで対応を行おうとしたのですが、以下のような
実装でprivateメンバにアクセスできません。

```
    namespace testSpace
    {
        class testClass: public ::testing::Test
        {
        public:
            foo obj;
            int getNum(){ obj.testNum; }
        };
    }

　　class foo
    {
            friend class testClass;
        private:
            int testNum;
    };
```

テストコード側に名前空間があり、テスト対象に名前空間がない場合に
フレンドクラスを使ってprivateメンバにアクセスしたいときは
どうすれば良いのでしょうか。

gtestを使っており、どうしてもテスト側(testClass)には名前空間を付けたいという
状況で、テスト対象のコード（foo）はテスト側の名前空間に含めたくないです。

逆のパターン（テストコード側に名前空間がなく、テスト対象に名前空間がある）
については既に解決策を見つけたのですが、今回のような場合をどのように
対処すれば良いか解決策が見つからなかったため、こちらで質問させていただきました。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++言語では宣言と定義を分離することができます。

```
namespace testSpace {
    class testClass;
}
```

このように`testSpace::testClass`クラスが（内容を定義することなく）存在することだけを宣言できます。事前に宣言されていれば、

```
class foo {
    friend class testSpace::testClass;
private:
    int testNum;
};
```

このように当該クラスをフレンド指定できます。

名前空間についてはどこであっても関係なく、名前空間無しの`testClass`であれば`friend class ::testClass`と明示するだけのことです。

Comment: 解決致しました、ご丁寧に説明していただきありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

どういうことがなさりたいのか今一理解できていませんが、
先行して宣言だけすれば良いのではないかと思うのですが、どうなんでしょう。
(ためしてません)

```
namespace testSpace
{
    class testClass; // 宣言のみ
}

using namespace testSpace;// これも必要

class foo
{
    friend class testClass;
    private:
        int testNum;
};

// 
namespace testSpace//実体はこっち
{
class testClass
//  : public ::testing::Test
{
public:
    foo obj;
    int getNum(){
        int     a = obj.testNum;
        return a;
    }
};
}
```

Comment: できました！ありがとうございました。